# RSS feed undefined item element validation error

Tags: xml, rss, nunjucks, eleventy

When I try to validate my RSS feed, It is giving me the below errors:

1. line 6, column 0: Undefined channel element: id
2. line 11, column 124: XML parsing error: :11:124: not
   well-formed (invalid token)

can someone help me out?

Here's the output:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Blogs about buying guide</title>
<link href="https://www.homeserve.com/en-us/rss/buying-guide.xml" rel="self"/>
<link href="https://www.homeserve.com"/>
<id>https://www.homeserve.com</id>
<lastBuildDate>November 11, 2021</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<title>Shower Organization and Storage Ideas</title>
<author>Mark Soto</author>
<link href="https://www.homeserve.com/en-us/blog/buying-guide/shower-storage/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.homeserve.com/en-us/blog/buying-guide/shower-storage/"/>
<pubDate>November 11, 2021</pubDate>
<id>
https://www.homeserve.com/en-us/blog/buying-guide/shower-storage/
</id>
<description type="html">
<img src=https://library.homeserve.com/m/6c3db5cf93aac7f6/Blog-GettyImages-1297624660.jpg alt=Blue bottle bath fluid in a clean and comfortable bathroom > <p>Having an organized shower is crucial to making your showering experience smooth and relaxing. There are many types of shower organizers, and choosing the right one depends on different factors. Apart from functionality, shower organization also affects the aesthetic of your bathroom and impacts how much space you have.</p> <p><strong>This May Also Interest You:</strong> <a href="https://www.homeserve.com/en-us/blog/how-to/low-flow-showerhead/"><strong>Here’s How to Hack Your Low-Flow Showerhead ... But Should You?</strong></a></p>
</description>
</item>
</channel>
```

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I have updated my description with the output.

Comment: Heh, I wanted you to *add* it :) can you share your code _and_ the output?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know for certain which lines are "Line 6" and "Line 11" that were mentioned in the errors.

**Error 1 (Line 6):**

The **id** element is not defined in the RSS 2.0 Channel Schema. It doesn't validate because it is not in the specification.

For a list of elements in the channel schema, see: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#requiredChannelElements

**Error 2 (Line 11) "XML parsing error":**

I think the **&** symbol is the issue on line 11. It is reserved in XML must be escaped:

```
& is escaped as &amp; in XML
```

This is the part to review:

```
/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss"/>
```

I have not been able to confirm escaping is required inside a url parameter value, but I believe the & is triggering the XML validation error.

**Invalid Image Tag:**

The parameters in the img tag are missing quotes and a final slash to be valid XML.

Original:

```
<img src=https://library.homeserve.com/m/6c3db5cf93aac7f6/Blog-GettyImages-1297624660.jpg 
     alt=Blue bottle bath fluid in a clean and comfortable bathroom >
```

Should be:

```
<img src="https://library.homeserve.com/m/6c3db5cf93aac7f6/Blog-GettyImages-1297624660.jpg"
     alt="Blue bottle bath fluid in a clean and comfortable bathroom" />
```

You can get more detailed RSS Validation feedback pasting your code into the WC3 Feed Validator: https://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input